# Maze Game In Visual Basic. Cursor Collision With Pictureboxes

Tags: collision

I am making a maze game in Visual Basic. How do I make a collision with the cursor and the picturebox, is it something like this?

```
if curosr.position.intersectswith(picturebox1) then 
msgbox("HI") 
end if
```

Then I have 1,000 pictureboxes I have to do that for, so is there an easier way to that? Maybe like this?

```
for each picturebox in me.controls
if curosr.position.intersectswith(picturebox) then 
msgbox("HI") 
end if
```

Comment: Add a MouseOver event to each picturebox in a loop.

Comment: can you provide an example, I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Not a VB guy but define an event handler

eg.

```
Private Sub CollisionHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        'your code here
End Sub
```

Then in some thing like your each loop link the picture box to the above handler with

```
AddHandler picturebox.MouseOver, AddressOf CollisionHandler
```